# How to verify that X509TrustManager is correctly implemented on iOS/Android with Codename One

Tags: https, codenameone

As the title says, I'm in need of verifying this, because of the recent PlayStore warnings. I know our app does (almost) not customize the connections, we use the NetworkManager and ConnectionRequest from CN1. Now, I can´t find where or how CN1 establishes https connections, is there anyway I can verify or confirm that there are no issues with TrustManagers? I am assuming there should not be, but would like to confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codename One doesn't override the X509TrustManager and leaves the default in place which should be secure enough. However, if you want to be extra sure and possibly restrict trust in your application further to prevent potential issues you can implement your own [X509TrustManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/X509TrustManager.html) by placing it under the `native/android` directory hierarchy then binding it in a [native interface](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html).

If you do that be sure to read [this](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6346016?hl=en) first.